# OAUTH response.sendRedirect(url) giving IllegalState exception

Tags: servlets, oauth, response

I have an application where I am doing OAUTH 1.0 and I am getting redirected to the redirect URL that I send in the OUTH call. Now, I am also geting "code" parameter in the callback URL which is normal OAUTH behaviour which I can understand. Now, I want to have this callback URL page as an dummy page so that I can process the "code" that I get and then I can redirect the response to the actual page I want. I would like to do it this way as I would not like to expose the "code" credentials to the endusers as it can be security issue. Now - when I am doing this, after processing the "code", I am redirecting the same reponse to the actual page from dummy page, however, it is giving IllegalState Exception while redirecting. Has anyone face this senario especially in OAUTH ?

exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:435)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're already committing the response before you're doing the redirect. Please show the code that's doing the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was I had lots of JSP code below response.sendRedirect(url) which made it to throw this error as after redirection the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to.

So I added a dummy page such that there is no JSP code after response redirection

[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)